Conveying the function definition and a verb corresponding to map
I know that mapping is conveyed by application in math context.

In mathematics, a map or mapping is a function in its general sense.
= En mathématiques, une application est une fonction au sens général.

But how to convey map when used as a verb?

Can one use the verb envoyer (sur) to convey map (to) in this context?

C'est dur à lire... LaTex/MathJax ne sont pas supportés sur FSE.

Yes, envoyer is the normal translation, specially in recent texts, specially if you want a single word: faire correspondre can more easily become awkward. "La fonction Tartempion envoie X {vers | sur} le point qui blablabla". A map is not an envoi, though.

@jlliagre I edited the question adding a screed show of the compiled code.

@Dimitris TIL :-) A screed is a long, boring speech or piece of writing with a bad attitude, like a rant. If you’ve had enough and you’re not going to take it anymore, go ahead and write an angry screed.

From my math class (year 2000s) , I remember those classical sentences used when talking about injection, bijections etc.

Une fonction f d’un ensemble A vers un ensemble B est une relation de A vers B telle que à
chaque élément x de A correspond au plus un élément y de B, appelé image de x par f.


une fonction (...) fait correspondre un unique élément de l'ensemble d'arrivée à tout élément de l'ensemble de départ

voir :

https://mathematiques.lmrl.lu/Cours/Cours_2e/2e%20Relations%20et%20fonctions.pdf
https://cocalc.com/share/public_paths/458ccb924dfbc6dcc4de3ee6361501afdd776659


Yes, envoyer is fine. Cette fonction envoie ce segment sur cet autre segment would be an example.

Merci. Is it better to use associe instead of assigne? By the way, would the range (of the function) be conveyed by image?

I think both associer and assigner are fine. The range would be the image, yes. Or the codomaine ou ensemble d'arrivée if you want to make that distinction.

In French mathematical terminology, the text is about "fonction inverse" (ou "fonction récciproque" in case of bijection) where you say that x est l'antécedent de y par la fonction f.
https://www.bibmath.net/dico/index.php?action=affiche&quoi=./i/image.html
https://www.methodemaths.fr/fonctions_reciproques/
The literal translation of the first sentence

"In mathematics, a map or mapping is a function in its general sense"
==> "En mathématiques, une application est une fonction au sens général"

is mathematically incorrect (at least,in French), because
une fonction est généralement une application dont le résultat (y) est numérique (a function is generally an application whose result (y) is numeric).
